# How to go from prototype to production

Tags: hardware

This question deals with Raspberry Pi but it is not limited to it.

I have build some prototypes using Raspberry Pi. They work well. What should I do if I want to transform my prototypes into production?

(this also applies to other boards as well, like the Jetson nano etc)

EDIT: Answer to commentators

1)Thanks tlfong01 for your comment. Unfortunatelly I am a software engineer with little training in hardware design but I think your comment is very much related to what I am asking. 
The site you cite is a service for PCB production, is it? Is there some tutorial or place I could learn how to proceeed? Say I want to use the services of Oshpark what do they require to build a PCB based on my prototypes? I will appreciate more input from you on this matter or your experience. Thanks!

2)Thanks Steve Robillard for the comment. 
What types of a prototype? It is inconsecuential.
Does this involve hardware, software or both? Both. 
Do you have a support service in place? 
How will people find out about your product? 
In what countries will you be selling this? 
do you have a lawyer? 
How will you accept and make payments?  Those are marketing issues that I am not concerned about yet. 
What I am asking is how to proceed from a prototype using RPi to a Printed Circuit Board that implements this behavior ready for production. Thanks

Comment: Are your going to try open hardware community PCB services? https://oshpark.com/.

Comment: Your question is very broad and only tangentially related to the Pi. What types of a prototype? Does this involve hardware, software or both? Do you have a support service in place? How will people find out about your product? In what countries will you be selling this? do you have a lawyer? How will you accept and make payments?

Comment: You remind me my story of learning CPLD (Complex Programmable Logic Device). I first read about CPLD in MagPi, way back in 2013. The Guzunty Pi guy made PCBs and I bought a couple from him, using PayPal, and he shipped to me the PCBs using British Royal Mail, with paper postage stamps! So I guess he is sort of  one man band. Anyway, I found him setting up a GitHub and a forum on Rpi.org. I am glad I learn much from them. Ref: (1)  Guzunty Pi – Open Source CPLD board for the Raspberry Pi - 2013mar28
https://raspi.tv/2013/guzunty-pi-open-source-cpld-board-for-the-raspberry-pi. / to continue, ..

Comment: (2) Guzunty Pi - New users start here - https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=41&t=49352&hilit=guzunty+pi …

Comment: For software guys who don't even know how to draw schematics, the learning curve is very steep (Eagle user guide is 500+ pages). Many newbies start with Eagle, because it is free for small footprints. But from Eagle to the real PCB still takes some time, if you are far away from the world factory - ShenZhen. So the MIT startup guys just stay there: (1) ShenZhen Factory Notes
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=91&t=222507&p=1366571&hilit=MIT+push+button#p1366571

(2) MIT Innovation Node in Hong Kong - MIT 2015Nov09
http://news.mit.edu/2015/innovation-node-hong-kong-1109.

Comment: "What types of a prototype? It is inconsecuential." That statement seems to be a lack of knowledge. It makes a big difference if your prototype only uses IO and basic calculating power compared to needing wifi, bluetooth and other functions that are way more complex. The reason is that the way to production looks vastly different 
 in both cases. As an example making a PCB with simple circuitry can be requested by PCB design companies relatively cheap whereas a complex layout with the full or almost full functionality of the PI is very expensive to a point where you just use the PI.

Comment: @VTMExpor Yes, I have a lack of knowledge, that is why I am asking. Thanks for the comment, it seems very useful. I have read that for production is not advisable to just use the PI. I wonder to ask for a PCB how is the circuitry of the PI replaced?

Answer (score 2):

In general if your prototype works: You look at all the functions it needs, then buy the according components to cover all the functions, make a pcb design, assemble the the pcb, test it and modify your pcb prototype till it works. 
When it works you send it to a certification facility to get it approved for sale.
If its approved you'll get in contact with manufacturing companies to mass produce it.

But that's not the only way. You can also send your PI prototype to a company specialised in making a finished device out of your prototype and skip the hardware development part.